# How to add Thousand separator in both axis of a 2-y axis chart in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

With this code, only the left y-axis changes. I need that the right y-axis changes too.
What can I do?

```
> df_F10_H20_summary
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Dataset count_by_Data_FH    sum_Fsize mean_Fsize median_Fsize
  <chr>              <int>        <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
1 BOND                 660 346088878101 524377088.    211524144
2 EQTY                1668 958120137292 574412552.    188492560
3 MIXED                572 214626691552 375221489.    139865165

scaleFactor <- max(df_F10_H20_summary$count_by_Data_FH) / max(df_F10_H20_summary$sum_Fsize)
#options(scipen=10000)
ggplot(df_F10_H20_summary, aes(x=Dataset,  width=.4)) +
  geom_col(aes(y=count_by_Data_FH), fill="aquamarine3", position = position_nudge(x = -.4)) +
  geom_col(aes(y=sum_Fsize * scaleFactor), fill="aquamarine4") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Number of Funds", 
                     sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name="Total Value of Funds"),
                     labels=function(y) format(y, big.mark = "'", scientific = FALSE)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("BOND",
                              "EQTY", "MIXED")) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y.left=element_text(color="aquamarine3"),
    axis.text.y.left=element_text(color="aquamarine3"),
    axis.title.y.right=element_text(color="aquamarine4"),
    axis.text.y.right=element_text(color="aquamarine4")
  ) +
  labs(title = "Number of Funds and Total value by Asset ", x = element_blank())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZuJj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sec_axis()` function has a `labels` argument which you can use. If you want the same formatting in each of the vertical axes, you can define it and use it e.g:

```
my_axis_format <- function(x) format(x, big.mark = "'", scientific = FALSE)
```

and replace the `scale_y_continuous(...)` part with:

```
scale_y_continuous(
  name     = "Number of Funds",
  sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scaleFactor,
                      name   = "Total Value of Funds",
                      labels = my_axis_format),
  labels   = my_axis_format)
```

That should give you the same formatting in both axes.

Comment: Wowwwww Amazing!!! Thank you so much!!! Have a great time!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Feel free to accept the answer if it meets your requirements! ;)